# How to fill only Selected cells of GridView with Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

My aim is simple. Assume I have 5 Lines of data which I filled in DataGridView. In 1st Column I filled data as shown below. User should fill the data in 2nd Column.

Name: --

Age: --

District: --

D.O.B: --

State: --

Now I have to place ComboBoxes in 2nd Column of DataGridView for "District" and "State" rows only and leave the remaining rows editable. With DataGridView I can make all Rows either ComboBox or TextBox. I googled for this but of no use. I tried 3rd Party tools also but this type of implementation I didn't find. I tried to take ListView/TreeView instead of DataGridView but I did not achieved. I am using C# Winforms VS2010.

If given any idea I am ready to start from scratch. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Below is the output where the highlighted "Rows" should be "ComboBox" and remaining should be "Textboxes".
[image]

If I add the below code whole Column is changing to ComboBox.

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn districtColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        districtColumn.DataPropertyName = "container";
        districtColumn.HeaderText = "Details";
        districtColumn.ValueType = typeof(Container);
        districtColumn.DisplayMember = "District";  
        districtColumn.ValueMember = "code";
        districtColumn.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(districtColumn);
```

Hope now You clearly understand my Problem.

Thanks..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a `DataGridView` representable data. Better look at the `PropertyGrid` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh... I got you this time.

What you need is [`DataGridViewComboBoxCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell(v=vs.110).aspx), create a comboxcell and place it in grid view cell.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell  cmbcell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cmbcell.DataSource = Districts; // Your data source

DataGridViewCell normalcell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
normalcell.Value = "Name"; // creating the text cell

dataGridView1.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[1] = cmbcell; // use your own logic to set row index
dataGridView1.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[1] = normalcell;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I'll chekout this one. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: No problem, post here if you have further questions/clarifications.

Comment: That doesn't work as ComboBox is applying to all the rows of the column.

Comment: @Gopi , I guess you are using combo column template for all columns, I've updated code for to declare other columns as well.

Comment: Ya Thanks it works fine. Just one more help, When I click on ComboBox Items are displaying, but items width is more than the combobox width. How to handle this one.